# Trying to import Pygal to Atom in MacBook

Tags: python, macos, atom-editor, pygal

I am really really new to python programming, and I wanted to try to make a Pie Graph using Python, as far as I know, I need to import `Pygal` to my Code. But it says

```
NameError: name 'pygal' is not defined
```

I've already tried to run `Pip3 install pygal` In my terminal and it says complete.

after that I tried to `import pygal` again, and it says the same thing.

I am Using ATOM editor

Your answers will be pleased.

Thank you,

_0K

Comment: Hi Omar, you are installing the package with pip3, but with interpreter are you running your code? WIth `python` or `python3`? If you install a package with `pip3` the package is going to be installed at `python3` environment, therefore, you should run your code with `python3` too.

Comment: Hi there! I am pretty sure that I've run in Python3. Perhaps, how do I know that I was running my code in python3? because I have python 2 and 3 installed on my laptop.

Thank you! @Guillem

Comment: Run `import sys; print(sys.version)` at the start of the script to know the python version

Comment: Ah Finally, found it. it says python 2.7.16 . Well I think that might be the problem? can I have a link to how to set my atom to run in python 3?

Comment: I don't knwo how atom runs the python scripts. Buth you can run the script from command line using `python3 script.py`

Comment: Thx, Still having problem tho. It says ```ImportError = no module named Pygal``` in the output. Although in the pip3, I've checked that the pygal is installed. any thoughts?

Comment: Run `python3 -m pip install pygal` and in the same terminal run the script with `python3 script.py` to make sure that you are not changing between virtualenvironments

Comment: Ok I found the Fix. this is what I do, 
I change the default atom ```Python.coffee``` from Python, to python3. Then I restart the atom Make a new file, save it. Then run the ```import sys; print(sys.version)``` Code, and it says 3.8.3. Then try to ```import pygal``` and it works just fine. 

Thank you so much for your thoughts @Guillem. :)